# Imputing missing/cutover values across multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How would I go about imputing missing/cut-over values across multiple columns in a dataframe like below, with the following cases:

1. Cases A & C: Impute value for Month3 from average of Month2 and Month4 values
2. Case B: Collapse two rows to fill in the 0 values across the four months

```py
df_input = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A','B','B','C'],
             'Month1': [10, 15, 0, 0],
             'Month2': [20, 32, 0 , 100],
             'Month3': [0, 0, 45, 0],
             'Month4': [50, 0, 51, 400]})


ID  Month1  Month2  Month3  Month4
A   10      20      0       50
B   15      32      0       0
B   0       0       45      51
C   0       100     0       400
```

My expected output dataframe would then be:

```py
df_output = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A','B','C'],
             'Month1': [10, 15, 0],
             'Month2': [20, 32, 100],
             'Month3': [35, 45, 250],
             'Month4': [50, 51, 400]})

ID  Month1  Month2  Month3  Month4
A   10      20      35      50
B   15      32      45      51
C   0       100     250     400
```

Comment: What is your expected output dataframe?

Comment: Hi Scott, just added the expected output dataframe in my original post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df_input = df_input.mask(df_input == 0)
df_out = df_input.groupby('ID').first()
df_out.interpolate(axis=1).fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  ID  Month1  Month2  Month3  Month4
0  A    10.0    20.0    35.0    50.0
1  B    15.0    32.0    45.0    51.0
2  C     0.0   100.0   250.0   400.0
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks it worked for this imputation problem!